# Rust - How to check EOF in File?

Tags: rust, bson

I am trying to implement the last exercise of https://github.com/pingcap/talent-plan/blob/master/rust/building-blocks/bb-2.md.

In short, I need to serialize some enums to bson, write to a file and read them back from file.
I got stuck in checking whether EOF is reached. I googled for some time but failed to find an answer.

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::{create_dir_all, OpenOptions};
use std::io::{Write, Seek, Cursor, SeekFrom};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use std::str;
use bson;
use bson::{encode_document, decode_document};

fn main() {
    let dir = Path::new("D:/download/rust");
    create_dir_all(dir).expect("Cannot create dir");

    let txt = dir.join("move.txt");

    // Encode some moves
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .create(true)
        .open(&txt)
        .expect("Cannot open txt");

    encode_and_write_move(&mut file, &Move::Up(1));
    encode_and_write_move(&mut file, &Move::Down(2));
    encode_and_write_move(&mut file, &Move::Left(3));
    encode_and_write_move(&mut file, &Move::Right(4));

    // Decode and print moves
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .open(&txt)
        .expect("Cannot open txt");

    loop {
        let end_of_file = false; // How?
        if end_of_file {
            break;
        }

        let doc = decode_document(&mut file).expect("cannot decode doc");
        println!("doc = {:?}", doc);
    }
}

fn encode_and_write_move<W: Write>(writer: &mut W, mov: &Move) {
    let serialized = bson::to_bson(mov).unwrap();
    let doc = serialized.as_document().unwrap();
    encode_document(writer, doc).expect("failed to encode doc");
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Move {
    Up(i32),
    Down(i32),
    Left(i32),
    Right(i32),
}
```

**Update:**
It seems the only way to see if EOF is reached is to check the returned Err. Here is my attempt for the whole exercise.

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::{create_dir_all, OpenOptions};
use std::io::Write;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use std::{str, io};
use bson;
use bson::{encode_document, decode_document, DecoderError};

fn main() {
    let dir = Path::new("D:/download/rust");
    create_dir_all(dir).expect("Cannot create dir");

    let txt = dir.join("move.txt");

    // Encode some moves
    let mut writer = OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .create(true)
        .open(&txt)
        .expect("Cannot open txt");

    encode_and_write_move(&mut writer, &Move::Up(1));
    encode_and_write_move(&mut writer, &Move::Down(2));
    encode_and_write_move(&mut writer, &Move::Left(3));
    encode_and_write_move(&mut writer, &Move::Right(4));

    // Decode and print moves
    let mut reader = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .open(&txt)
        .expect("Cannot open txt");

    loop {
        match decode_document(&mut reader) {
            Result::Ok(doc) => println!("doc = {:?}", &doc),
            Result::Err(DecoderError::IoError(e)) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => break,
            Result::Err(err) => panic!("Decoding failed with {}", err)
        }
    }
}

fn encode_and_write_move<W: Write>(writer: &mut W, mov: &Move) {
    let serialized = bson::to_bson(mov).unwrap();
    let doc = serialized.as_document().unwrap();
    encode_document(writer, doc).expect("failed to encode doc");
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Move {
    Up(i32),
    Down(i32),
    Left(i32),
    Right(i32),
}
```

Comment: Why EOF? I guess you just have to check the `DecoderResult` returned from `decode_document`.

Comment: @aventurin see my reply for the muhuk's answer below

Answer (score 0):

`bson::decode_document` returns `DecoderResult<Document>` which is an alias for `Result<T, DecoderError>`.  <del>If you check possible values for enum `DecoderError`, you will see [`EndOfStream`](https://docs.rs/bson/0.13.0/bson/enum.DecoderError.html#variant.EndOfStream)</del> It seems `decode_document` returns a `Result::Err<DecoderError::IoError<_>>` in case of an EOF.

So instead of trying to detect EOF in your code, it would be more straightforward to consume the stream (by repeatedly calling `decode_document`) until an error is raised.  Then the error can be handled, or in case of `EndOfStream` processing can continue normally.

You can try something like this:

```rust
loop {
    match decode_documment(&mut file) {
        Result::Ok(doc) => println!("doc = {:?}", &doc),     
        Result::Err(DecoderError::IoError(io_error)) => match io_error.kind() {
            std::io::ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => break,
            _ => panic!("Decoding failed with I/O error {}", io_error)
        }
        Result::Err(err) => panic!("Decoding failed with {}", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work because the code panics in case of EOF. It is quite confusing that `IoError(Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "failed to fill whole buffer" }` is returned when EOF, and I am not sure if it is a good practice to check for this error rather than checking EOF before calling decode_document().

Comment: Could be my mistake identifying the `EndOfStream` as the EOF value.  What is the exact output when the code panics?

Comment: Thanks but your code doesn't compile, the best I came up with is `Result::Err(DecoderError::IoError(e)) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => break,`

Comment: Sorry about that.  You are right, you can't pattern match on `kind` field because it's not a field.  I will update the code above to a slightly more readable version of what you got though.